# Placing an element vertically between (and on top of) two other elements

Tags: css

Below the `header` element on top of my page I have a `#container1` element with text content in it. I want to display a third `#sub_header` right between the two and on top, as shown on this [mockup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0gVA.jpg).

I could make `#sub_header` go on top of header by applying `position:relative` and a negative top margin to it. But I don't know how to have the upper part of the `#container1` element "come" below `#sub_header`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: screenshots won't help you, provide the code you tryed and one might give you some hints , even an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this you're looking for?

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
#sub_header{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: -50px auto 0;
}
#container1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgb(220,220,220);
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="sub_header"></div>
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Comment: You should combine your margin statements into margin: -50px auto 0;

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. I don't understand how it works though. "Left:0" and "right:0" mean the element's width is 100% of the screen, so should it not somehow conflict with the "width:300px" ?